# Yii CActiveForm - please wait message

Tags: yii

We wish to trow a modal popup telling the user to "please wait" until the forms finishes submitting.

Here is part of my **_form.php** (just a snipped for readable proposes):

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'event-form',
        'enableClientValidation' => true,
        'clientOptions'=> 
              array('validateOnSubmit'=>true, 
                'afterValidate'=>'js:function() {     
                         $("#publishErrors").empty();
                         $("#event-form_es_").empty();
                         i = true;
                         if($("#EntityEvent_active").is(":checked"))
                         {
                          $("#publishErrors").show().append("<p>Please check:</p>")
                          if($("#Event_name").val()=="")
                          {
                            $("#Event_name").addClass("error"); 
                            ...
                            ...
```

I confess I'm a little lost on this process and I'm not sure if this will even work, still:

I'm thinking about placing this:

```
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog'
        , array('options'=>array(
            'title'=>'My Title'
            , 'modal'=>true
            ))
);

echo 'Please Wait While Your Form is Being Submitted';

$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
```

at the very end of 'afterValidate' -

Is there a better approach ?

Please advice

Comment: the comments for my post have been migrated automatically to chat i believe. anyway, when you come back, leave me a comment, and i shall come to that chatroom, to help you out. also it'll be difficult to tell you where exactly to open the dialog, without looking at your submit code

Comment: had some mistakes in my code before, please check updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a jquery plugin for this: [jQuery BlockUI plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#page).

But if you want to use CJuiDialog, just make sure that `closeOnEscape` is `false`, and `modal` is `true`, also `autoOpen` should be `false`.

You could also use a [jQueryUI Progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/) inside a CJuiDialog to show progress if you wish.

Edit:

Sample code to hide x button of the dialog:

```
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',
    array(
        'id'=>'mywaitdialog',
        'options'=>array(
            'title'=>'My Title',
            'modal'=>true,
            'autoOpen'=>false,// default is true
            'closeOnEscape'=>false,
            'open'=>// supply a callback function to handle the open event
                    'js:function(){ // in this function hide the close button
                         $(".class-of-closebutton").hide();
                    }'
         ))
);
```

To open the dialog: `$("#mywaitdialog").dialog("open");`.

You can open the dialog in afterValidate, as you had guessed. While the form data is passed to the server the dialog will show, and after completion url navigation will occur(new page will be loaded).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13773/discussion-between-mem-and-bool-dev)